# Why are CPU caches faster than RAM?

Tags: cpu

Can the same technology/idea that is used to make caches fast not be used to make RAM fast too?

Or is there a fundamental tradeoff to be made here between speed of access vs. size of the store.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the question is. But CPU cache is of course faster because it doesn't need to travel to the RAM (Electric). When u are asking what are some examples are. I Would just think of a simple loop.

Comment: Because they're closer.

Answer (score 2):

[Cost](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Dynamic_random-access_memory_vs_Static_random-access_memory). Cache is SRAM and main memory is DRAM. Different technologies, different use cases. You couldn't afford a computer that used SRAM for (a reasonable amount of) main memory.

Comment: An interesting detour into something I didn't know anything about. https://www.microcontrollertips.com/dram-vs-sram/ TL;TD: the SRAM is more expensive because it uses several transistors per bit whereas DRAM only uses 1.

Comment: Yep - you picked that up in time for me to edit it. BTW surely SRAM as main RAM would still be slower than cache due to the round trip as the comments suggest? That was my assumption as to the main reason for the speed difference.

Comment: @seesharper While the round-trip does have an effect the access time of SRAM vs DRAM is usually more significant. That's the reason implementing cache on the motherboard (yes, that used to be a thing,  Apple used to do this a lot) is till faster than main RAM.

Answer (score 0):

**The Distance:** CPU is much more tightly packed than a RAM and therefore electric signals need to travel a lot longer.

**How they work:**

1. RAM uses a small capacitor that’s connected to the transistor which stores a tiny charge. This charge will not stay long and it needs to be constantly refreshed to maintain its state which makes it slower.
2. CPU Cache on the other hand uses a flip-flop gate which retains its state without refreshing. It’s more expensive to develop but it’s much faster.